# Is it preferred to create tables in mysql using a third party application (phpmyadmin, TOAD, etc...) versus php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it preferred to create tables in mysql using a third party application (phpmyadmin, TOAD, etc...) instead of php?

The end result is the same, I was just wondering if one way is protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a 'set-in-stone' program to manage your database and query to it.

However, I highly recommend [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

It allows you to graphically design your database, query to your database server and do all kinds of administration tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is far easier to do so within an application created for that purpose.  The database itself obviously doesn't care as it's just DDL to it. Using Toad or PHP MyAdmin would help you do the job quicker and allow you to catch syntax errors prior to execution or use a wizard where you're not writing it by hand in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

usually a software project provides one or more text files containing the ddl statements to create the necessary tables. what tool you use to execute those statements doesn't really matter. some php projects alwo provide a installer wizard php file which can be executed directly in the browser, so you don't need any additional tools at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to only answer what your question is - "*Is it preferred to create tables in mysql using a third party application (phpmyadmin, TOAD, etc...) instead of php?*"...

Yes, it is preferred to create tables or alter them or delete them or perhaps do any DB-related activity that is outside the scope of what interfaces your application provides, in MySQL using any of the many available MySQL clients. And the reason is because these applications are designed to perform DB related tasks and are best at doing them.

Though you may as well use PHP for creating tables depending on the situations, like if the application uses dynamic tables or needs "temporary" tables for performing complex jobs or storing intermediary results/calculations. Or perhaps if the application provides interfaces to manage/control certain aspects, like assume that a certain application consists of various user-roles that have their respective columns in the table. If the application provides rights to the admin to delete or add new roles, which will need to delete or add new columns, it's best to do such queries from PHP.

So, putting it again, use MySQL for any DB work that is not related or affected by what functionality or interfaces your PHP code provides.

Sidenote: Though I've used phpMyAdmin, TOAD, WorkBench and a few others, I think nothing's as efficient and quick as the MySQL client itself, i.e. working directly on the MySQL prompt. If you've always used GUI clients, you might find it unattractive to work on the prompt initially but it's real fun and helps you keep syntaxes on your tips :-)

Answer (score 0):

**You question might have been misunderstood by some people.**

Charles Sprayberry was saying there's no best practice as far as which 3rd party MySQL client (i.e. phpmyadmin, TOAD, etc.) to use to edit your database.  It comes down to personal preference.

Abhay was saying (and I really think this was the answer to your question), that typically, your application does not do DDL (although exceptions exist).  Rather, your application will usually be performing DML commands only.

*DML is Data Manipulation Language.  For example:*

- `select`
- `insert`
- `update`
- `delete`

*DDL is Data Definition Language.  For example:*

- `create table`
- `alter table`
- `drop table`

[Basic SQL statements: DDL and DML](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php)